# Why should we take one degree less numerator in Partial Fraction Integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, order-of-integration

In the method of Integration using partial fraction method, the numerator is always kept to have 1 degree less than that of the denominator. 
Say, numerator would be Ax+B for a second degree denominator but just A for a linear denominator.

Why is it necessary to have a one degree one reference? I get that not having one degree less would cause problems when we solve the problem because we won't have all the variables to pair their coefficients, but I am seeking a more intuitive explanation.

Comment: Not necessarily an explanation but it helps to integrate to a log function

Comment: Because if it were larger the problems  becomes integrating a polynomial plus a fraction and one is still left with the  problem integrating a fraction.